# How does R decide the x and y axis of mosaicplot

Tags: r

I am curious how R decides x and y axis of mosaic plot?

```
data(HairEyeColor)
mosaicplot(HairEyeColor)
```

It puts the "Hair" at x-axis and "Eye" at the y-axis and break the Sex.
Is it predetermined?

What will happen if we have more than 5 variables and do the mosaic plot?

Answer (score 0):

See: [Mosaic Plot vignette](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/mosaicplot.html)

> xlab, ylab:    x- and y-axis labels used for the plot; by default, the
>   first and second element of names(dimnames(X)) (i.e., the name of the
>   first and second variable in X).